# Problems with variables working outside idle loops in apple script

Tags: applescript

I have a problem with variables not working outside an idle. What should I do to make it work? My code looks like this:

```
set currentdate to current date
set currentminute to currentdate's minutes
on idle
    display dialog currentminute
    if idle_time < 0 then set idle_time to days - (time of (current date))
    return idle_time
end idle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on idle` is not a loop, it's a handler having its own scope.

Mark `currentminute` as `global` or declare it as `property` for example. Both ways makes the variable available in handlers on lower levels.

```
property currentminute : 0

set currentdate to current date
set currentminute to currentdate's minutes

 on idle
    display dialog currentminute
    if idle_time < 0 then set idle_time to days - (time of (current date))
    return idle_time
end idle
```